# Rails 5 group by, sum and show in view

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models in Rails 5 and usign Postgres:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
attribute :total (among others)
   belongs_to :categorys
end  

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  attritubte :name (among others)
  has_many :sales
end
```

so how can i get sales group by category and sum the total of sales in each category? and how can i show it in my view (in a instance variable). For example i want to show  in my view this:

CategoryOne : Total $3000 (maybe the result is a hash but how can i show it in the view?

CategoryTwo : Total $4000

CategoryThree : Total $2200

and so on....

which is the right rails way query (active record)? and how to show the results in view? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the combined `total`s of a category's sales by using ActiveRecord's [`#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum):

```
category = Category.last
category.sales.sum(:total)
```

---

To render the sales totals in your views, you can do something like this:

In the category model:

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  def sales_total
    sales.sum(:total)
  end
end
```

In your relevant controller action:

```
# app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
@categories = Category.includes(:sales)
```

And in the corresponding view:

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <%= "Category #{c.name}: Total $#{c.sales_total} %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: and how can i pass an argument to the method sales_total(date), so i can filter the total by a date. I should pass the date in the controller or in the view? How can i do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def sales_total_on(date)
  sales.where(date: date).sum(:total)
end
```

You can pass the date through the request parameters from a form to a controller. You could use a select or a datepicker.